# Who orders Saga around in Dreamfall Chapters

Tags: dreamfall-chapters

In the fifth book of Dreamfall Chapters

> when Saga helps stop the Azadi Engine she refers to someone (???) who told her about the "very specific prophecies" which detail what will happen. Later when she has a conversation with Kian she tells him that she'll explain but there is no explanation.

So my question is this: who orders Saga around?

> It is also interesting that Lux and Nox met and the world was not un-dreamed despite they were talking about that there was time for undreaming. What happened?